# Thread is not sleeping when told to do so

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

I have a method that creates a thread in C# that runs a method (CallCheckLogic - as seen below) Although I have specified for a sleep to occur (Thread.Sleep(60000);) the methods (e.g. ChecksObject.Check1Logic()) Keep looping, its like the sleep thread method is being ignored. It doesn't make logical sense to me, would someone be able to explain why this behaviour is happening?

**Expected Result:** A new thread is created, method CallCheckLogic is called which itself calls ChecksObject.Check1Logic >> ChecksObject.Check7Logic and then then Thread.Sleep(60000); is called, causing the thread to sleep for 60 seconds, a loop is then run and the CallCheckLogic is run again.

```
private void StartCheckerThread()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(o =>{CallCheckLogic();});t.Start();
    running = true;
}

public void CallCheckLogic()
{
    Checks ChecksObject = new Checks();
    ChecksObject.Check1Logic();
    ChecksObject.Check2Logic();
    ChecksObject.Check3Logic();
    ChecksObject.Check4Logic();
    ChecksObject.Check5Logic();
    ChecksObject.Check6Logic();
    ChecksObject.Check7Logic();

    // This method / delegate parses the outfile of "temp" or rather the results of the tests and turns on / off the appropriate light on the GUI
    LightControlDelegate d1 = new LightControlDelegate(lightControl);
    this.BeginInvoke(d1);
    Thread.Sleep(60000);

    //LoopPorts();
}
```

**ChecksObject.Check1Logic method**:

```
public void Check1Logic()
{
    // clean up time! 
    File.Create("temp").Dispose();

    // lets grabs the info from the config!
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("probe_settings.ini");
    var dictionary = lines.Zip(lines.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { Key = a, Value = b })
                          .Where(l => l.Key.StartsWith("#"))
                          .ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => l.Value);

    // lets define variables and convert the string in the dictionary to int for the sock.connection method!

    int portno1;
    int.TryParse(dictionary["#PortNo1"], out portno1);

    // Convert hostname to IP, performance issue when using an invalid port on a hostname using the TcpClient class! 
    IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname2);

    foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
    {
        // Attempt to create socket and connect to specified port on host
        TcpClient tcP = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        try
        {
            tcP.ReceiveTimeout = 1;
            tcP.SendTimeout = 1;
            tcP.Connect(theaddress, portno1);
            tcP.Close();
            StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("temp");
            sw.Flush(); 
            sw.WriteLine("Check1=Success");
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("temp");
            sw.WriteLine("Check1=Fail");
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the title...Hilarious :):):)

Comment: But seriously, the CallCheckLogic() thread will Sleep(). What makes you think it doesn't? You left out the looping part(s).

Comment: Because, I can see on my network monitor that the remote ports that are bing checked with the "ChecksObject.CheckXLogic" methods are being continuously (almost like the methods are looping) I have added the ChecksObject.Check1Logic method (they are all pretty much the same)

Comment: It's still unclear what LoopPorts() does and how/why "the CallCheckLogic is run again"

Comment: There's no looping in the supplied code. Obviously something external to the code shown is relevant here.

Comment: And if your comments are correct, you should not call CallCheckLogic again, from within CallCheckLogic, eventually (it may be a long time), you'll have a stack overflow. Instead, you should place a while-loop or similar around the entire body of that method.

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should not sleep in any noticable way, it just sleeps just before the thread's method ends. If you call a method StartCheckerThread() in a loop placed somewhere in the code that is not posted here, you should move Thread.Sleep() to the StartCheckerThread() method or put it directly inside that loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any loop here. Your `CallCheckLogic` method is called once then it ends and the thread stops executing.
Maybe there is an infinite loop in one of your `CheckXLogic` so your thread appears to be working all the time, but I can say it's not likely there is a problem with the Sleep call.

Try to add breakpoints just before and just after the `Sleep`, you'll know if this line of code is ever executed.